# Symfony FOSRestBundle exception error 404

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I try to add an exeption when i a page not found, 404.

So i add this is ocnfig fos_rest :

```
#    exception:
#        codes:
#            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
#            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
#        messages:
#            'Acme\HelloBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage': true
```

But i have this error :

```
FOSRestBundle exception mapper: Could not load class 'Acme\HelloBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage' or the class does not extend from '\Exception'. Most probably this is a configuration problem.
```

Comment: Does `'Acme\HelloBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage'` extend `\Exception`?

Comment: like this  'Acme\HelloBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage' extend \Exeption : true ?
With this i have error  : not contain valid YAML

Comment: show the code of `Acme\HelloBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage' class

Comment: I don't find it, so i think i don't have 'hellobundle'... I look for have it

Comment: Ok i have create my own exeption and its ok, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped.I posted it as an answer.Please consider accepting it and /or upvoting it.Happy programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the namespace is acme it looks like you copied some demo tutorial code and the bundle doesn't exist.

You need to create your OWN exception class extending \Exception and pass its namespace there in the yml .